# Text Prediction with word and character LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I'm trying to implement an LSTM with both character and word embeddings as shown [here](https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/lstm-with-char-embeddings-for-ner/), except my problem is not NER, just simple text prediction. Right now I'm getting this error:

```
   ValueError: Shapes (None, 135) and (None, 10, 135) are incompatible
```

This is my model summary:

```
Model: "model_13"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_34 (InputLayer)           [(None, 10, 30)]     0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_33 (InputLayer)           [(None, 10)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_43 (TimeDistri (None, 10, 30, 20)   2380        input_34[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_16 (Embedding)        (None, 10, 128)      26887296    input_33[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_44 (TimeDistri (None, 10, 20)       3280        time_distributed_43[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_14 (Concatenate)    (None, 10, 148)      0           embedding_16[8][0]               
                                                                 time_distributed_44[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout1d_14 (SpatialDr (None, 10, 148)      0           concatenate_14[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_14 (Bidirectional (None, 10, 100)      79600       spatial_dropout1d_14[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_45 (TimeDistri (None, 10, 135)      13635       bidirectional_14[0][0]           
==================================================================================================
Total params: 26,986,191
Trainable params: 98,895
Non-trainable params: 26,887,296
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

My inputs are `X_word`, `X_char` and `Y`. `X_word` is a list of encoded words. 10 words per sentence `(2770, 10)` And `X.word[0]` looks like this:

```
array([[ 16871,      298,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,      0,
             0,      0]])
```

And it's a padded sentence with two words.

My X_char is a list of characters for those words:

```
array([[  7, 101,  16, 101,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0],
       [ 56, 102,  16,  34, 102,  61,   6, 102,  93,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0]])
```

X_char has a shape of `(2770, 10, 30)`.

I have 135 labels so Y is in shape `(2770,135)` and i fit everything like this:

```
history = model.fit([X_word_tr,
                    (np.array(X_char_tr)).astype('float32').reshape((len(X_char_tr), max_len, max_len_char))],
                    np.array(to_categorical(y_tr)), epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

I can't help but think my logic is flawed somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you defined the model like in the tutorial you linked (which you should include in the post), it's because it's set to return a sequence, so it returns the next 10 characters. You need to set `return_sequences=False` so it returns a single value, and remove the last `TimeDistributed` layer that wraps around the last `Dense` layer.

```
main_lstm = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=False, 
                                                               recurrent_dropout=0.6))(x)
out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_tags + 1, activation="sigmoid")(main_lstm)
```

In the summary, you will see that it returns a single value, and so it can be compared to your labels:

```
_______________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)                 (None, 135)          13635       bidirectional_5[0][0]            
===============================================================================================
```

Comment: now im getting this: 
```InvalidArgumentError:  indices[310,0] = 119 is not in [0, 119)
  [[node model_3/time_distributed_12/embedding_7/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-64-51f6ad92087d>:3) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_28785]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node model_3/time_distributed_12/embedding_7/embedding_lookup:
 model_3/time_distributed_12/embedding_7/embedding_lookup/24179 

Function call stack:
train_function

```